# Linq to XML Insert a new element into the XML for each node

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-xml

I would like to insert a new element in the following XML for each instance of a data node

**Here is the initial XML that I have:**

```
<dataCollection totalCount="12" pageCount="1">
    <data>
        <date>2011-11-10T00:00:00.000-05:00</date> 
        <dataType>PRCP</dataType> 
        <station>GHCND:USW00014739</station> 
        <value>267</value> 
        <address>
            <home>X</home> 
        </address>
    </data>
    <data>
        <date>2011-11-10T00:00:00.000-05:00</date> 
        <dataType>PRCP</dataType> 
        <station>GHCND:USW00014739</station> 
        <value>267</value> 
        <address>
            <home>X</home> 
       </address>
    </data>
</dataCollection>
```

**And this is the XML I am trying to achieve**

```
<dataCollection totalCount="12" pageCount="1">
    <data>
        <date>2011-11-10T00:00:00.000-05:00</date> 
        <dataType>TMIN</dataType> 
        <station>GHCND:USW00014739</station> 
        <value>267</value> 
        <newValue>60</newValue>  
        <address>
            <home>X</home> 
        </address>
    </data>
    <data>
        <date>2011-11-10T00:00:00.000-05:00</date> 
        <dataType>TMAX</dataType> 
        <station>GHCND:USW00014739</station> 
        <value>270</value>
        <newValue>62</newValue>  
        <address>
            <home>X</home> 
        </address>
    </data>
</dataCollection>
```

The XML data is used as a data source for a DataGrid using the following Linq.

```
Dim elements = (From daDsc In xdoc.Descendants("data") _
            Select Data_Type = daDsc.Element("dataType").Value, _
            Raw_Value = daDsc.Element("value").Value,
            newValue = daDsc.Element("newValue"))
```

Writing this in VB.net, but answers in C# is OK. Thanks.

Comment: How do we know what value to put in the `newValue` element for each `data` element?

Comment: Are you trying to `Load` xml, change it - add `newValue` under each `data` node - and then use as `Data Source` with the query your provided? Meaning the new xml is volatile and not saved anywhere?

Comment: @JakeJacobsen - You need to use the "@" notation to ensure that the person you are replying to gets a notification. It was only luck that I came back and looked at this question.

Comment: @JakeJacobsen - Also, your reply doesn't help in the coding of the response. You need to provide the mechanism - for example, "there's a function that maps `station` to the new value".

Comment: @Enigmativity Thanks for clarifying. Eventually, there will be a function that maps `value` to `newValue`, but for now, I'm just trying to figure out how to add a dummy element to the XML using Linq (or  XPath).

Comment: @Neolisk I get the current XML from a web service, it is not loaded from a file. It is not persisted/saved. It is in memory, so yes it is volatile. I was wondering if there's a way to add the `newValue` element in the Linq statement too. Can I create a New Element in the `Select Data_Type...`?

Comment: @JakeJacobsen: you can't create elements in `Select` - see my answer - I think this is what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach (var xe in xml.Descendants("data"))
{
    xe.Element("value")
        .AddAfterSelf(new XElement("newValue", 42));
}
```

Comment: @Neolisk - Thanks. I wanted to use a "meaningful" value.

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes, that worked! Thanks a ton. For completeness, here is the solution in VB.net   `For Each xe As XElement In xdoc.Descendants("data")
                        xe.Element("value").AddAfterSelf(New XElement("newValue", 42))
                    Next`

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to add `newValue` into your XML before processing, you could do something like this:

```
For Each element As XElement In xml.Elements
  element.SetElementValue("newValue", "something")
Next
```

where `xml` is an `XDocument`, loaded from your web service.